# Trying to recall the name of a book I read in the 80's

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book or short story where kids did not go to school or read books.  When they reached a certain age they were programmed.  The programming did not work on some kids and they were sent away.  The kids that were sent away were really the smart kids who developed the programming tool for the other kids.  What was the name of that book?

Comment: This does not have an accepted answer and **should be reopened**.

Comment: The accepted answer being https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6642/story-where-the-protagonist-is-turned-off-from-an-automated-system-of-profession, although we still can't mark this one as a dupe.

Answer (score 14):

This could be the story ["Profession"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profession_(short_story)), by Isaac Asimov (1957.)

Answer (score -4):

That could perhaps be the [Tripods trilogy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tripods) by John Christopher.

Comment: Why would you say it matches? (Yes, I know this is a very old answer of yours... but it's never too late)