# Story about a student that does not learn like other students

Tags: story-identification

This student doesn't learn by rote and is singled out as an individual thinker that can innovate.

He was fearful that he would not pass his exams about repairing space craft but in the end he proves to be much better than the other students.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about science fiction or fantasy

Comment: I was going to say "Harrison Bergeron" but the spaceship angle threw that out of the window :-) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWiddy20DqU

Comment: Can you elaborate: is it a science fiction story (you mention 'space craft')? When did you read it? Novel or short? Any idea when it was published (recently or an old book)?

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like a garbled memory of ["Profession"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profession_%28short_story%29) (1957) by Isaac Asimov, where the student in question cannot learn a profession direct from the machines, but must learn the old-fashioned way. He eventually learns he has been chosen to create the programs for the teaching machines.

A full version is available to read online [here](http://www.abelard.org/asimov.php)

Comment: Previously identified in answer to [this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6642/story-where-the-protagonist-is-turned-off-from-an-automated-system-of-profession).

Comment: @user14111 - Both his recent questions are from an anthology called "Nine Tomorrows" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_Tomorrows

Comment: Maybe he will recognize one of [the covers](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?29890).