# Looking for a story about Children being tested and 'placed' in their careers

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult

I remember reading this book/story, maybe 25-30 years ago

It was a story about a society that had their children tested for aptitude.  Whatever they scored well in determined what they should study to prepare for their life's work.  After the test was given, the machine/computer would score it, and the candidate would know immediately what course of study they would do best in.  Math, architecture, biology, engineering, teaching, etc...

The main character was a child who took the test, and unlike his best friend, did not get an immediate response.  He took this lack of answer as a personal failure and that he was not fit for any kind of work.  His friend did get a response, and almost immediately started excitedly studying for his career.

After some time of ambiguity, the child is put into a 'generic' school.  Nobody tells him specifically what he is supposed to be working towards, and he is taught a little bit about a wide variety of topics.  He does okay, but has a lingering feeling of ambiguity, and doubt - since he hasn't been assigned a career.  This isn't helped by his old friends who were ribbing him about how he doesn't have a focus of study.

It isn't until very late in the book, that he finds out that the reason he wasn't given a career, was because his specialty was **Synthesis**, or the bringing together of everyone else's specialties.  They are a rare, treasured, and precious thing in the world.  "We have thousands of people who can do architecture and math, but only the rare few who can combine their efforts and do something truly useful."

I strongly remember the title "synthesist" being assigned to the main character in this story.  Anyone know/heard about this story?

Update:  I just finished reading Isaac Asimov's "Profession."  While the two do share the concept of the "testing children", I don't recall there being any interplanetary aspects, or instant learning in the story I am trying to find.  The story I recall still had the children in classes for years afterwards, and the conclusion did not involve an escape, and visit to the local Profession Olympics.  Might there be a similar story out there?

Update2:  There was a second suggestion.  The moving walkways and having to break in and change test scores also do not sound familiar.  I will try to find that story and read it.  Until then, I can't confirm for sure.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Story where the protagonist is turned off from an automated system of professional attribution and instant learning](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6642/story-where-the-protagonist-is-turned-off-from-an-automated-system-of-profession)

Comment: @KyleJones No. See the last paragraph edited into the question.

Comment: @Otis - No mention of synthesists in that, at least that I saw.

Comment: I'm reading a book called "Heretic", by David Beers. In it, children are tested then assigned to a future place in society. Children that don't meet the standards are termed "unessential" and liquidated. Literally. This isn't the story you're looking for.
Another story I read long ago was about a child that was being tested for IQ. In that story, the child was terminated because his IQ was too high. I don't remember who wrote that one.

Comment: @KyleJones - We don't mark story-ident questions as duplicated until they've been confirmed by the OP.

Comment: Doing a quick and dirty search brings up a couple options on Google. While none of them immediately stand out as great matches, [Beyond This Horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyond_This_Horizon) by Heinlein might be close. As I have not read the book I cannot say if it matches beyond having "synthesist" in the wikipedia page.

Comment: @Xantec Great find. I haven't read it either, but I might have a copy around here somewhere. Doesn't mean I can find it.

Comment: @Xantec If *Beyond This Horizon* **is** the right book, the OP should be able to find something [here](http://www.heinleinsociety.org/concordance/books/bth_hc.htm) that rings a bell.

Comment: "We have thousands of people who can do architecture and math, but only the rare few who can combine their efforts and do something truly useful." - is that an actual quote or just something that to illustrate the theme of the story

Comment: @Nathan That was more to illustrate the theme of the story.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions.  I actually own a copy of _Beyond This Horizon_, although the writing style of this story doesn't seem like Heinlein, I'll read through it again to see if it matches.  Any excuse to read one of my Heinlein books. :)

Comment: Sounds like several modern societies.

Comment: It seems that 'Divergent' by Veronica Roth was heavily influenced by this book because the plot sounds very similar. Although it can't be the book you are looking for because it was written in 2011. 'The Giver' by Lois Lowry is similar too, written in 1993 but I don't remember anything about 'synthesis', a boy was separated from his classmates and given special training.

Comment: A couple of points reminded me of *Brave New World* but it's not that - I guess the testing from a young age leading to assigned careers is a pretty common trope, and there's no off-planet aspect,  but *Brave New World* heavily uses instant (or rather sleep) learning

Answer (score 3):

I'm going on a long shot, and the mention that a male character ends up becoming a synthesist, that you may be remembering Alexei Panshin's [Rite of Passage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rite_of_Passage_(novel)). The story is told by Mia who wants to be a synthesist. By the end of the book, she's changed careers to an ordinologist and Jimmy is going to be the synthesist.

Mia and Jimmy live on a generation ship. When they turn 14, they'll be put down on a planet to survive for a month. If they survive, they'll be considered adults and begin work on their careers.

Comment: Probably not, seeing as the OP doesn't recall "there being any interplanetary aspects."