# Sci Fi story about injecting books into kids' brains

Tags: story-identification, books, isaac-asimov

I remember a story (by Asimov maybe?) about a future in which teaching in school is done through infusing the material into kids' brains?

One kid doesn't fit in life because his brain isn't assimilating the knowledge. At the end he finds where the books are created, and he goes on to write the books.

[image: "At School" by Jean-Marc Côté]

(Picture: "At School" by Jean-Marc Côté / ["In the year 2000"](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:France_in_XXI_Century_(fiction)) post card series / public domain)

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site, including tips on story identification questions. For more story id hints, I recommend having a look [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info). As it is, this is a fairly common trope, and the question thus runs the risk of being closed as too broad.

Comment: [This one?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6642/story-where-the-protagonist-is-turned-off-from-an-automated-system-of-profession)

Comment: source: http://publicdomainreview.org/collections/france-in-the-year-2000-1899-1910/  by Jean-Marc Côté, no copyright

Comment: You can read Asimov's "Profession" [here](http://www.abelard.org/asimov.php).

Comment: @user14111 cool. thank you very much! I think it might be it, I'm reading it now.

Comment: @TastySpaceApple Waiting with bated breath for your verdict. If it's the right story, we can close the question as a duplicate. If not, we need to know more details about the one you're looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Story where the protagonist is turned off from an automated system of professional attribution and instant learning](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6642/story-where-the-protagonist-is-turned-off-from-an-automated-system-of-profession)

Comment: OP sounded fairly positive about match and hasn't been back; seems safe to assume it is a duplicate.

Comment: @Otis I'm voting to leave open as I don't think that it's safe to assume when it comes to duplicates. We should wait for OP confirmation.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to me to pretty clearly be the story *Profession* by Isaac Asimov.

> I remember a story (by Asimov maybe?)

Yep, it's by Asimov.

> about a future in which teaching in school is done through infusing the material into kids' brains?

To quote Wikipedia, the story is set in a society "in which children are educated by almost instantaneous direct computer/brain interface, a process known as taping".

> One kid doesn't fit in life because his brain isn't assimilating the knowledge.

When the main character goes to get tested for which profession he will be "taped" to join, he isn't allowed to join any, and is instead sent to a "House for the Feeble Minded", because he is "unable to be educated".

> At the end he finds where the books are created, and he goes on to write the books.

After the bulk of the story, the main character realizes that the tapes (and the knowledge on them) need to come from somewhere and that the "house for the feeble minded" actually is for the people who are creative enough to make the tapes. He is therefore someone who is truly innovative enough to create those tapes.