# 50s-60s short story: implanted knowledge, except for the protagonist who has to solve his issues the usual way

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

There was a short story from back in the 50s or 60s, about a student who was struggling in school.  Just about everyone else had knowledge downloaded/implanted into their brains.  But the protagonist had to work out problem solving his tests the hard way.

Society and the protagonist felt that he was the "unintelligent" one, but in reality he was being groomed to be a true leader with well developed problem solving abilities.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6642/story-where-the-protagonist-is-turned-off-from-an-automated-system-of-profession

Comment: Hi Fred, please review the answer below and click the checkmark to the left if it's correct; if it's not correct, you can comment on the answer to indicate such.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Story where the protagonist is turned off from an automated system of professional attribution and instant learning](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6642/story-where-the-protagonist-is-turned-off-from-an-automated-system-of-profession) (this is the same comment as @Otis, but with the dupe flag)

Comment: @stannius policy on story-id is to only dupe-close when both answers are accepted (whether with a checkmark or "that's it" comment). Since there's no such a thing on the present question, we should leave it open for now.

Answer (score 41):

I believe you are thinking of Asimov's "[Profession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profession_(novella))".  Most people are 'tape-educated' via a kind of brain-induction, but our hero is told his brain isn't fit for it, and he's sent to the 'House for the Feeble Minded.'

Eventually (after most of the story) he realizes that it's actually an

> Institute of Higher Studies, but that candidates have to find that out on their own and understand his place in their society.

You can read it online, [here.](https://www.abelard.org/asimov.php)

Comment: Fred, if this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left. Please do; it will show everyone the mystery was solved and reward both you and KHW with some reputation :)

Comment: This was the story I thought of, as well.

Comment: Wow, that page is...something

Comment: But, why do they call it Olympics?

Comment: @Kevin What's really fascinating to me is the clash between the modern social media buttons and the 1994 look of everything else.