# Storyline book identification

Tags: story-identification

Good evening to all of you. I am puzzled by the search of a book, that I read in childhood and forgot the name of it or the author. I only remember the plot and tried to find it with the help of ChatGPT or Gemini of Google, but no help. If anyone has any idea about it?
I am looking for a book I read in the past. It is fictional one. The plot goes as follows: futuristic society is relying on the machine learning and young people do not study in school, but rather get their knowledge transferred to them via super computer. So it is transferred to their brains at the age of 18 when they become adults. One young boy was curious enough and started visiting old libraries and read books, and all of his friends were laughing at him, claiming, that there is no point in learning, because the machine will give them all the knowledge based on their biological properties and abilities. But the young boy persisted. At the day of the ceremony and transfer of knowledge the machine could not give the young boy any knowledge and he got way behind all of his classmates, who got the knowledge easily. He was claimed to be unworthy or not chosen one and was told, that his brains do not suit for knowledge. He was told, that he has to do so the old-fashioned way - through hard learning manually. He then begun his studies, but of course was way behind all the others. He then got frustrated and wondering - why did machine decided that way? At the end he found out, that it was important to see, if he will persist in getting the truth and seeking the truth, because his willingness to study even before he got access to the knowledge from the machine - it is what determines the creative mind and he is the future of humanity, that will drive the changes and will made the new inventions.

It should be a science fiction novel, other characters, that may play important role: is that a boy had to undergo a learning with a group of other similar people, all of them struggling with learning manually, reading and studying books one by one. The protagonist also has a mentor, who is helping him on his journey of learning. At the end of the book the boy then discovers, that all those, who persisted and learned hard way arespecial ones, who then will build the nation and humanity further on, because they remained curious and were striving for knowledge despite all the odds against them. This also opens doors for him to be elite and chosen ones who will help humanity.

Thank you!
Kind regards,
Dima

Comment: Likely this is [*Profession*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profession_(novella)) by Isaac Asimov.

Comment: And if so, a dupe of [Story where the protagonist is turned off from an automated system of professional attribution and instant learning](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6643/20774)

Comment: It's worth saying that "when I was a child" doesn't help us solve this, as we don't know how old someone is.  Saying "in the 1970s or 1980s" DOES help tremendously.

Comment: @Valorum Another duplicate - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/276942/sci-fi-story-about-a-future-in-which-students-are-evaluated-to-determine-the-fie?noredirect=1&lq=1